# How to plot the X axis data point for uneven tick interval at in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am having a unequal data values in X axis the data point is plotted in the center of the tick interval, kindly see the fiddle link [http://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/w4oyx8Ln/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/w4oyx8Ln/2/). Please see the 3rd point of the black line (9.4, 1.879) inspite of using the x-axis unequal interval code

```
  tickPositioner: function() {
    var tickPositions = [];
    Highcharts.each(this.series[0].options.data, function(p) {
      tickPositions.push(p[0]);
    });
    return tickPositions;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you are using numbers in your `xAxis.categories` array does not mean that they are treated as numbers. They are treated as literals that are separated by 1 index value from each other. From the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories):

> If categories are present for the xAxis, names are used instead of
>   numbers for that axis

If you want the xAxis to be numeric then you need to set your x values to be numbers in your data points.

Setting up x/y values in your points:

```
data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 7.7918348462852,
        color: 'RGBA(128,128,128,0)',
        segmentcolor: 'RGBA(128,128,128,0)'
      }, {
        x: 0.5,
        y: null,
        color: 'RGBA(128,128,128,0)',
        segmentcolor: 'RGBA(128,128,128,0)'
      }, {
        x: 1.8790271054655,
        y: 7.6224396161563,
        color: 'RGBA(128,128,128,0)',
        segmentcolor: 'RGBA(128,128,128,0)'
      }]
```

Remove `categories` from you xAxis properties.

Live [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/w4oyx8Ln/5/) of a smaller set of your data.